# Sorbet can't find `validates` method when including `ActiveModel::Model`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorbet

I'm using ActiveModel to validate some form objects in my Ruby on Rails. A simplified reproducible example looks like this:

```rb
# typed: true

class Form
  include ActiveModel::Model
  
  # ...

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The issue is, Sorbet complains that `validates` does not exist on `T.class_of(Form)`. Even though the RBI files are properly generated for the `ActiveModel::Model` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because it is really hard for Sorbet to understand the mechanics of what `ActiveSupport::Concern` does.

What is happening here is that when `include ActiveModel::Model` is called, it then includes `ActiveModel::Validations`. But since both `ActiveModel::Model` and `ActiveModel::Validations` are concerns, both `ActiveModel::Model::ClassMethods` **and** `ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods` are added to `Form` using `extend`. It is the `ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods` that provides the `validates` method, and that `extend` is what Sorbet cannot see statically.

First of all, the basic `srb` tooling has no knowledge of `ActiveSupport::Concern` and will not generate proper `mixes_in_class_methods` calls to make Sorbet aware of the `ClassMethods` that are also in play. Moreover, even if that was generated, it would only apply at one level of include and would fail in this case.

The workaround is to explicitly add an `extend ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods` in `Form`, but that is ugly.

The best solution is to switch over to Tapioca tooling to generate proper RBI output for concerns. We will also soon start generating a solution for nested concerns like this, which should solve this properly.